# global.asax how to call Method of a dll component

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I'm new in ASP.net, 
so I want to know how can I access to the method of a DLL component without initialise it,
in asp I write like this and its work :

```
<object runat="server" scope="session" id="apiName" progid="PROGID">     </object>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">
SUB Session_OnStart
APINAME.FUNCTION....
END
```

but in asp.net When i call this object i can't find method of this object , for example this object called apiname has a function called test, when i type apiname.test it show the following error: Error  1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'test' and no extension method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

That object tag you used to use is just sugar syntax for creating an instance of the object. You can do the same in one line of C# in your code, so what's the problem?